# How to end the program when a user enters "quit"

Tags: c, exit

How can I end the program when a user enters "quit"?  I tried an if statement before the loop and within the loop. I'm pretty new to programming and it's bothering me that I can't figure this out. I even tried a do while loop and that didn't work at all.

```
int main()
{
    char word[30];
    char yn;
    int loopcount;
    yn=0;
    loopcount=0;
    printf("Enter a word:");
    scanf(" %s", word);
    printf("Would you like to change the word? y=yes, n=no \n");
    scanf(" %c", &yn);
    if (yn=='n')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    while(yn>0)
    {
        printf("Enter a new word: \n");
        scanf(" %s", word);
        printf("New word is: %s \n");
        loopcount= loopcount+1;
        printf("You have changed the word %d times.\n", loopcount);
        printf("Would you like to change the word? y=yes, n=no\n");
        scanf(" %c", &yn);

        if (yn=='n')
        {
            return 0;
        }


        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the word in `printf("New word is: %s \n");`

Comment: Do you know how to use `strcmp()` to compare two strings? Use it to compare `word()` with `"quit"`. If they match, return from the program.

Comment: What's the point of `while (yn > 0)`? How would it ever become 0? Just use `while(true)`, since you exit when they type `n`.

Comment: Save time and enable all warnings.  Compiler should have warned about `printf("New word is: %s \n");`.

Comment: `if (yn=='n')
        {
            return 0;
        }


        return 0;` always returns 0.

Comment: You can combine the prompting and input all within your `while` loop since you keep a `loopcount`. Within the `while` loop just check `if (loopcount == 0) printf("Enter a word:"); else printf("Enter a new word: \n");` and you could use the same `if` before `printf("You have changed the word %d times.\n", loopcount);` to handle that case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strcmp()`

```
scanf(" %s", word);
if (strcmp(word, "quit") == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was really bothering me haha.